# How to INSERT $_SESSION variable in database?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I stuck at following problem: I want to INSERT the $_SESSION['userID'] in my database, but it is not working. It inserts nothing into the database with following code. Security is not important in this case!

```
if(isset($_POST["joinKurs"])){
    echo("<script>console.log('userID: ".$_userID." and KursID: 1 saved in database');</script>");
    $_sql = "INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('{$_SESSION['userID']}','1')";
    $_res = mysqli_query($link, $_sql);
}
```

When I replace {$_SESSION['userID']} with a number, it works.

```
    if(isset($_POST["joinKurs"])){
    echo("<script>console.log('userID: ".$_userID." and KursID: 1 saved in database');</script>");
    $_sql = "INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('5','1')";
    $_res = mysqli_query($link, $_sql);
}
```

echo $_sql shows that the SQL Statement is wrong.

```
INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('3');','1')
```

Comment: Using prepared statements would make this a lot easier.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($_SESSION['userID']);`?

Comment: You are outputting `$_userID` but trying to store `$_SESSION['userID']` - needless to say these are not the same thing at all.

Comment: But it doesn't matter which one I use. Both are not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $_sql = "INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('".$_SESSION['userID']."','1')";
```

Use this, as `'` using this will not print the value inside the variable, and the sql string getting create is invalid.

i.e

```
"INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('{$_SESSION['userID']}','1')";
```

What you need is

```
"INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('12345646edj','1')";
```

Also , use

```
echo $_sql
```

to verify the sql statement created.

Comment: I get a syntax error now.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: check i have removed `{ }`, also verify the sql generated to identify the exact error.

Comment: The syntax error is now gone, but still nothing will sent to my database.

Comment: Just put `echo $_sql;` below to print the query getting generated and run it directly against the db. There might be certain column constraints like length of data to be inserted which may be creating problem if query is proper.

Comment: I put
echo $_sql;
at the end, still no changes.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $_sql;` ? A sql statement will get printed on your screen. Run that statement against db directly to check if its valid or not.

Comment: Echo shows: INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('3');','1')

when I write that directly in db, it says: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: This is a inavlid sql statement `INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('3');','1')` kindly verify the statement again what i put in first statement.. Your code seems to be different according to the output.  Are you using `$_sql = "INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('".$_SESSION['userID']."','1')";` this ?

Comment: Yes, I use:
$_sql = "INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('".$_SESSION['userID']."','1')";

The ('3'); is the mistake, right? But why, is it writing there.

Comment: May be `('3');` is the session value, you can confirm this by printing session variable externally, and then parse that to make it proper for inserting to db.

Comment: The Session value is 3, when I echo it. That is correct. It has to be a number. But the ';' doesn't fit in the SQL Statement. I have no idea, why it shows up there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try storing the session id into a variable and see if it's working
like so :

```
$sid = $_SESSION['userID'];
$_sql = "insert into userkurse (userID,kursID) values ('$sid','1')";
```

Plus, try echo'ing the $_SESSION['userID'] and see if it's returning a valid value.

Look at this :

```
$_SESSION['userID'] = 3;
$_sql = "INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['userID']."', '1')";
echo $_sql; // this returns : INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES ('3', '1')
```

Comment: I tried that before, but it is also not working. The echo of the session works.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you echo $_SESSION['userID'], it returns a valid int right ?

Comment: Yes, echoing works fine and correct. In the comments under Atul Sharma's answer you can see, that the sql statement is wrong. It writes:
INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('3');','1')
which doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, i tried echoing the query and it's fine : INSERT INTO userkurse (userID, kursID) VALUES('5','1')

Comment: What's session id returning exactly when you try to echo it ?

Comment: Yes, when I enter a number instead of $_SESSION['userID'] then it works. When I echo $_SESSION['userID'], it returns a number. In this case: 3.

Comment: That is so strange. When I echo the SESSION['userID'] or $_userID, it shows me the correct userID. But when I put it into the sql statement, it adds and ';' behind the userID.

Comment: That's strange, try the code solely in another empty page and see, you need to debug your code line by line, surely there's something fishy about that whole php page, look at my edit